# How to match dataframe by match column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I'm new to pandas. I'm trying to join two datasets as below:

df1:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1121, 1122, 1123, 1124, 1125], 'name': ['F.01', 'F.01', 'F.02', 'F.02', 'F.02'], 'description': ['r1', 'r2', 'l1', 'l2', 'l3']})
```

Looks like:

```
  id  name description
1121  F.01 r1
1122  F.01 r2
1123  F.02 l1
1124  F.02 l2
1125  F.02 l3
```

df2:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'code': ['F.01', 'F.02'], 'r1': [1, 0], 'r2': [2, 0], 'l1': [0, 3], 'l2': [0, 4], 'l3': [0, 5]})
```

df2 looks like:

```
code  r1  r2  l1  l2  l3
F.01   1   2   0   0   0
F.02   0   0   3   4   5
```

The result I would like them match by

```
df1.name = df2.code
df1.description = df2.(column name)
```

The result I prefer is like:

```
  id  name description value
1121  F.01 r1          1
1122  F.01 r2          2
1123  F.02 l1          3
1124  F.02 l2          4
1125  F.02 l3          5
```

Thanks!

Comment: `df2.melt("code")` and then do a `merge` with `df1`.

Answer (score 0):

The general guidance by *Henry* is right, but it lacks some necessary details.

To get your expected result the following steps are required:

- rename *code* in *df2* to *name*,
- melt *df2* on *name*, setting *var_name* to *description*,
- merge *df1* with the above *melt* result on *name* and *description*.

The code to do it is:

```
result = pd.merge(df1, df2.rename(columns={'code': 'name'}).melt(
    'name', var_name='description'), on=['name', 'description'])
```

The result is:

```
     id  name description  value
0  1121  F.01          r1      1
1  1122  F.01          r2      2
2  1123  F.02          l1      3
3  1124  F.02          l2      4
4  1125  F.02          l3      5
```